# Is anonymous authentication possible with auth_code grant in Spring Security OAuth2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement an OAuth2 client with SpringBoot 1.5.13 and spring-security-oauth2 2.0.15.RELEASE.

I want to be able to authorize **anonymous users** with auth_code grant.
However I'm running into issues when trying to finish the auth flow.
Since I don't want to call any other external service to obtain user identity info, I'm using the `DefaultTokenServices`. The `DefaultTokenServices` needs a TokenStore for it's operation, so I'm supplying the simplest one - `InMemoryTokenStore`.

I have tried two approaches that both failed:

### 1. Redirect to OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter

If I redirect user after authorization grant to a URL, that `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` filters on, the filter properly requests and obtains an access token. However, the next thing it tries to do is:

```java
OAuth2Authentication result = tokenServices.loadAuthentication(accessToken.getValue());
```

And that call fails on `BadCredentialsException("Could not obtain user details from token")`, because the `DefaultTokenService` tries to call `tokenStore#readAccessToken`, but the `InMemoryTokenStore` is entirely empty at this point.

### 2. Redirect to another URL (simple RestController)

If I redirect user after authorization grant to another URL, that doesn't match the `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, I cannot even obtain the access token.
When trying to call `restTemplate.getAccessToken()` in the RestController, the call fails in `AccessTokenProviderChain` due to this exception:

```java
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

***EDIT:*** I've tried to use my own implementation of `AccessTokenProviderChain`, that simply omits this check, and the parts related to `clientTokenServices` and at first look it seems to work. But I am not sure if this is a correct approach sufficient for multitenancy (multiple anonymous concurrent users authorizing via multiple OAuth2 providers).

Obviously my auth is an anonymous auth, I **need** an **anonymous** auth flow! I know It is perfectly possible in Spring Security 5.2.x, but I don't understand how to do this in spring-security-oauth2?

Is it not possible to do anonymous authorization with auth_code grant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems anonymous auth is not possible together with OAuth2 auth_code grant, as explained in this open bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1842

I've solved the issue by ditching the spring security oauth library and moved to ScribeJava.